# CSS images not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing a Rails 4.1.4 web app and when I deploy to Heroku
images that are referenced inside the CSS files are not being show.

Other images that I am referencing with image_tag works fine (they also got the token attached to their names). How can this be?

**Update**

Solved it with background-image: image-url("stripes.png");

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with background-image: image-url("stripes.png");